# Wordpress - Displaying images in widget area

Tags: php, wordpress

I have to do following - create page lets say with one big gallery and then find a way to randomly display 9 images from this gallery in widget area in sidebar. Any tips on how to proceed with the issue?

Comment: How far are you with the solution? Please visit the help center and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what to ask and how.

Comment: I am just trying to figure out the way to do it.. searched google for what I could but nothing specific because I didn't know what to search for.

Answer (score 0):

What ill suggest is to create [Custom WordPress Widget](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-wordpress-widget/)

Then you will need to create `WP LOOP` that will get all attachments for the page and randomize 9 of them.